# Make prepros watch Jade HTML include files

Tags: html, include, pug, prepros

How can I make prepros watch HTML include files in Jade templates?

Gets a bit tiresome having to save the Jade file too after updating the included HTML. Codekit has this feature, any ideas how to get it working in Jade?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make it too, but I use simple hotfix which you might like.

1. Rename your `example.html` file to `example.jade`
2. Select your file contents and make indent.
3. Write any tag with a dot on top of the file, with no indents on the left (it is a top level tag).

   ```
   span.
     <html> ...
   ```

   Now you can edit `example.jade` as a simple .html file. Hope it will help.